# Coding Challenge Speed Issue. Find elements from 2 arrays matching a given sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time-complexity, big-o

You have two integer arrays, a and b, and an integer target value v. Determine whether there is a pair of numbers, where one number is taken from a and the other from b, that can be added together to get a sum of v. Return true if such a pair exists, otherwise return false.

Example

For a = [1, 2, 3], b = [10, 20, 30, 40], and v = 42, the output is true because 40 + 2 = 42.

The above is my problem. I have the correct solution but I want a better way to write the solution...I want it to run faster. I'm currently using two for loops:

```
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
    for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if(a[i] + b[j] === v) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how much faster you could get

Comment: you can get lots faster depending on how large the arrays get

Comment: And not fast enough to solve it on this site:
https://codefights.com/interview/qAL6AiSejoJZRNyox/description

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number

Comment: You could use a binary search tree which could turn this from O(n^2) into O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn one of the arrays into an array indexed by the values. Then loop through the other array, and test whether `v - element` is an element of the array.

```
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
    var test = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        test[a[i]] = true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (test[v - b[i]]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this has hashing auto with using objects instead of array +1. try with `test ={}`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve linear complexity if you first create a set from array `a` that will contain results of `v - a[i]`. This will take `O(len(a))`.

Then you iterate over `b`, and check if `set.get(b)`, which is `v - a[i]`, exists.  If it does, then `v - a[i] === b[i]` so `a[i] + b[i] === v`. This will take `O(len(b))`.

The total complexity is thus `O(len(a)) + O(len(b))` (checking existence in a set is `O(1)`).

From this follows that, if the arrays have equal lengths, the complexity is `O(2N)`, which is `O(N)`.

Here's the code:

```js
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
  const setOfRemaindersFromA = new Set(a.map(num => v - num));
  return b.some(num => setOfRemaindersFromA.has(num));
}

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4],
      b = [10, 20, 30, 40];
      
console.log(sumOfTwo(a, b, 42)); // true
console.log(sumOfTwo(a, b, 45)); // false
```

*Note*: Check out [Barmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42684936/3928341) for a pre-ES6 solution of this approach.

---

If the arrays can have different lengths, you have to build the set from the shorter one and iterate over the longer one to make sure all elements are covered.

Comparing array lengths is a constant operation so this doesn't affect the overall complexity.

```js
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
  const [shorter, longer] = a.length > b.length ? [b, a] : [a, b];
  const setOfRemaindersFromShorter = new Set(shorter.map(num => v - num));
  return longer.some(num => setOfRemaindersFromShorter.has(num));
}

const a = [1, 2],
      b = [10, 20, 30, 40];
      
console.log(sumOfTwo(a, b, 42)); // true
console.log(sumOfTwo(a, b, 45)); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks!! I tried the following:

```
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
    var a = a.sort();
    var b = b.sort();
    for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(var j=b.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
           if(a[i] > v && b[j] < v) {
                break;
            }
            if(a[i] + b[j] === v) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please let me know if I could improve that more!

Comment: my answer may be the slowest passing on average please check others performance too (epascarello and Barmar)

Answer (score 1):

Passed it with hashing and lookup

```
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
    const x = a.reduce( (o,a) => { o[a]=1; return o; }, {})
    return b.some( b => { return x[v-b] })
}
```

If the arrays are sorted, could probably speed it up more to jump out of the loops if values are greater than `v`

Answer (score 0):

Checking with brute force is O(n*n)

Sort two arrays. Start from elements smaller than **v** and go to decreasing direction.(others will overflow for sure) Sorting can be O(nLogn)

```
 a ---> a'   O(nlogn)
 b ---> b'   O(nlogn)

binary search to elliminate a(i) > v and b(i)>v O(logn)
```

now you have much less values to continue as O(n*n)

Comment: hey! benchmark Barmar's answer: . that could be faster with hashing with object instead of array. I didn't calculate worst case yet